# Spring Security Authorization Server with custom AuthenticationProvder

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm having a problem configuring an Oauth2 Auth Server in Spring, I have my custom AuthenticationProvider and I'm defining my own AuthenticationManager, but everytime that I do a request for a token to "/oauth/token", I see that Spring keeps injecting and calling the default DaoAuthenticationProvider in the ProviderManager defined by Spring.

This are my configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    private ADCustomerService adCustomerService;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(ADCustomerService adCustomerService) {
        this.adCustomerService = adCustomerService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return adCustomerService.retrieveUser(username, authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your custom authentication provider?

Comment: @silentsudo it's in my project and is annotated with "@Service"

Comment: @silentsudo just added the class in the origina post

Comment: I tried to help you with a suggestion, but I will recommend using https://www.keycloak.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class

The final class should look something like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it's the same, stil seeing DaoAuthenticationProvider but not my provider

Answer (score 0):

Edit your WebSecurityConfig  as follows:

**FROM**

```
  @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
        public WebSecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
            this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        }
    
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
        }
    }
```

**TO**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```